# How to convert Listview to DataTable

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, listview, datatable

I have seen many examples of populating a listview from a datatable or converting a datatable to a listview but what I am trying to do is exactly the other way around.

How can I convert/copy the contents of a winform listview to a datatable?

[EDIT]

I have a listview with a context menu where users can multiselect items and choose one of the context menu options, I then loop the selected items and extract each selected row (listview item) and serialize it, instead of doing this I wanted to convert the listview to a datatable then add the datatable to a dataset and serialize the dataset.

Thanks

Comment: Just do the opposite.  What have you tried?  What part of the task are you having trouble with?  Create a new DataTable, create the columns to match the ones in the list view, then add the rows.

Comment: lets see some code of how your wiring things up from your datatable to your listview

Comment: retrieve Listview items which you want into a **List<Type>** and then just use **List<Type>.ToDataTable()** or **.ToDataView()** method..if you can't see in your List ext options let me knowledge..i can give you an extension method for this

Comment: I have edited the question, but I think I got the concept of this. thanks for the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like that (totally untested)

```
var listView1 = new ListView();
DataTable table = new DataTable();
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
{
    table.Columns.Add(item.ToString());
    foreach (var it in item.SubItems)
         table.Rows.Add(it.ToString());
 }
```

Comment: tested this and it works, and made some small changes and I can do what I want now, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 3):

Accepted answer doesn't look right to me. Here is a tested alternative:

```
public static void FromListView(DataTable table, ListView lvw)
{
   table.Clear();
   var columns = lvw.Columns.Count;

   foreach (ColumnHeader column in lvw.Columns)
      table.Columns.Add(column.Text);

   foreach (ListViewItem item in lvw.Items)
   {
      var cells = new object[columns];
      for (var i = 0; i < columns; i++)
         cells[i] = item.SubItems[i].Text;
      table.Rows.Add(cells);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 DataTable table = new DataTable();

            table.Columns.Add("MODUL", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("ACIKLAMA", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("UZUNLUK", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("GENISLIK", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("MIKTAR", typeof(string));

            for (int i = 0; i < listView2.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(listView2.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text, listView2.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text, listView2.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text, listView2.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text, listView2.Items[i].SubItems[4].Text);
            } //Which Subitems you want to add in the listview
```